# Importing Module that doesn't exist in sys.path

Tags: python, spyder

I have functions that I am importing from a module:

```
    from SpatialPredictionFunctions2 import dbfreader, children, ContinuousAllocation, CategoricalAllocation, CountAllocation
```

This module is saved on my hard drive, so I do:

```
    sys.path.append('D:/Projects/StreamCat/Scripts')
```

which is where SpatialPredictionFunctions2.py is located.

If I open a new Ipython console in spyder and make the import before I append the directory where the module is kept, it will still import the functions.  I have looked in the sys.path directories and the module s not in any of them.

However, if I do a search in windows explorer for 'SpatialPredictionFunctions2' I see that it is located in the spyder.ini file.

I tried to edit out the line:

```
     u'C:\\Users\\Rdebbout\\Scipts\\SpatialPredictionFunctions2.py': []
```

from this .ini file, but it doesn't seem to be editable.

Does this .ini file add directories to the path behind the scenes? I'm a bit lost here.

Is there a way to check what script a module has been imported from after importing?

Comment: Is the module in `sys.modules` when you are able to import from it? It may be getting loaded somewhere else (before you its folder out of `sys.path`) and you're getting the cached version.

Comment: don't see it in sys.modules even after importing it doesn't show up there